# Docker runtime error after tar command

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2, gzip, tar

I am retreiving a `tar.gz` file using `wget` and unpacking it using `tar -xzf`. If I run the `tar` command from within the running container, it unpacks successfully and is stored as `init` in which I can then start the service with `./init`.

The issue I'm having is that when I use that same `tar` command from a `RUN` instruction in the `Dockerfile`, I always get the same error when `docker build .` gets up to any next instruction after the `RUN tar -xzf` command.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

And here is my Dockerfile for testing:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
RUN yum install -y wget tar gzip
wget https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v1.19.1.1/s6-overlay-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf s6-overlay-amd64.tar.gz
RUN echo "test"
```

**Note:** If I make `RUN tar -xzf` the final instruction in the `Dockerfile`, it will build successfully, but attempting to run the image in a container will lead to that same error.

---

**Further Troubleshooting Information:**

From within the container, I ran `which gzip` to confirm gzip is being used from the right path (`/usr/bin/gzip`), and I also ran `file https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v1.19.1.1/s6-overlay-amd64.tar.gz`, which produced the following output towards the end:

`Length: 1713081 (1.6M) [application/octet-stream]`

To my knowledge, `octet-stream` just means the file is a binary file, and the extension should be enough to tell me that this is a `gzip` file.

For what its worth, I know this `tar.gz` file is being successfully unpacked in another working Dockerfile built `FROM alpine:3.6`: https://hub.docker.com/r/webcenter/activemq/~/dockerfile/

I have tried the `tar` command used in the referenced `Dockerfile` and I always end up with the same error.

Comment: The referenced docker file pipes the output of curl directly into tar without creating a temporary file. Have you tried approach?

Comment: @MisterSmith yes and it works, but any `RUN` command afterwards gives the following error when building: `OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown`. I'll add this to the question to clarify that I have tried the original method.

Comment: Is tar an actual binary file or a wrapper script pointing at something else? Error seems to imply a script is starting

Comment: @MisterSmith I agree that is what it seems the error is implying. How can I find out whether or not its a binary file or a wrapper script pointing at something else? The fact that wget returns `[application/octet-stream]` implies its a binary file, no?

Comment: On a typical Linux developer machine, the `file` command will often tell you (or guess at) what kind of a file something is.  You may not have this tool inside a container, since it is much more of a developer tool.  It’s not impossible that `curl` decompressed the file for you.

Comment: @DavidMaze I installed `file` on my Docker container and ran it on the tar.gz file and got the following output: `/s6.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators`. In resposne to this output, I ran `less` on the file, and found out that I am being redirected to an Amazon server to serve the file. I'm continuing to troubleshoot with this new information.

Comment: Try adding `-L` to your curl call so it should follow the redirect

Comment: @MisterSmith That is the same as what I did in response to your first comment about doing what is done in the referenced Dockerfile. This works, but if I add another `RUN` command to the Dockerfile after unpacking what I receive from `curl -L`, I get the `OCI runtime create failed` error. This error also comes up in the Docker build if I use `wget` to get the tar.gz file and then unpack it using `tar -xzf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up not being a `Docker` issue but rather an issue with the `tar.gz` file I was trying to unpack. Multiple workarounds found [here](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/issues/125).